# Add one space before and after each string in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to add one space before and after each string in Python. I have 851 files. The first file contains 219 lines. The last file contains 1069 lines. Some line are just dots while other lines are numbers. I would like to use the center() function. I tried:

```
import os, os.path

for x in range(1, 852):
    input_file_name = f"9.{x}.txt"
    output_file_name = os.path.join(f"10.{x}.txt")
    with open(input_file_name) as input_file:
        with open(output_file_name, "w") as output_file:
            for input_line in input_file:
                output_line = input_line.center(2)
                output_file.write(output_line)
```

This does not add any space. I want one space before each string and one space after each string.

### Input

```
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
25
.
.
.
.
55
```

### Expected output

```
x.x
x.x
x.x
x.x
x.x
x.x
x.x
x25x
x.x
x.x
x.x
x.x
x55x
```

NB : `x` stands for space. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The length of each line matters! So take that into consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `input_line` in the above code will contain a newline at the end `\n` thus in your case you need to remove the `\n` character thus we can use `rstrip()` to remove newline and format line as you needed.

### Code

```py
 for input_line in f:
        output_line = " " + input_line.rstrip("\n") + " \n"
        output_file.write(output_line)
```

### Output

```py
 . 
 . 
 . 
 . 
 . 
 25 
 . 
 . 
 . 
 . 
 . 
 .
```

---

Comment: This does not add any space after the numbers.

Comment: okay .. is it compulsory to use center method . the reason was that the number has 2 digits hence taking center would leave the last 2 position with numbers

Comment: Yes, I want to use the center method.

Comment: without using center it would be easy .
        `output_line = " " + input_line.rstrip("\n") + " \n"`

Comment: `output_line = " " + input_line.rstrip("\n") + " \n"` is working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Moin Yellowcab,

as I understand correctly you can use the .join string method to add any values to the beginning and the end of a string.

```
#insert character into string with string-method .join

string_1 = 'this is a string without a space at the beginning or end. Put a X where the spacing should be'


iterable_join = ['X', 'X',] 
string_1 = string_1.join(iterable_join)
print(string_1)
```

Output in my console is:

> Xthis is a string without a space at the begining or end. put an x
>   where the spacing should beX

I don't know if this creates too much overhead but it does work. 
For more information see:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm

If it helped you to solve the question please mark as answer.
Best,
CJ